# Deserialize nested JSON and VB.Net (Postmark Json)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json.net

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831479/deserialize-nested-json-and-vb-net) I am trying convert this Postmark Json sample (loading from file) but am getting an error on executing :

```
{
  "TotalCount": 194,
  "Messages": [
    {
      "Tag": "Invitation",
      "MessageID": "0ac29aee-e1cd-480d-b08d-4f48548ff48d",
      "To": [
        {
          "Email": "john.doe@yahoo.com",
          "Name": null
        }
      ],
      "Cc": [],
      "Bcc": [],
      "Recipients": [
        "john.doe@yahoo.com"
      ],
      "ReceivedAt": "2014-02-20T07:25:02.8782715-05:00",
      "From": "\"Joe\" <joe@domain.com>",
      "Subject": "staging",
      "Attachments": [],
      "Status": "Sent",
      "TrackOpens": true,
      "TrackLinks": "HtmlAndText"
    }
  ]
}
```

I managed to create all classes allright:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PostmarkOne As Object = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("PostmarkOne.json"))
        Dim JsonPost As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(PostmarkOne)
        Label1.Text = JsonPost.Messages._To.Email
        Label2.Text = JsonPost.Messages.From
    End Sub

    Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property TotalCount As Integer
        Public Property Messages() As Message
    End Class

    Public Class Message
        Public Property Tag As String
        Public Property MessageID As String
        Public Property _To() As _To
        Public Property Cc() As Object
        Public Property Bcc() As Object
        Public Property Recipients() As String
        Public Property ReceivedAt As Date
        Public Property From As String
        Public Property Subject As String
        Public Property Attachments() As Object
        Public Property Status As String
        Public Property TrackOpens As Boolean
        Public Property TrackLinks As String
    End Class

    Public Class _To
        Public Property Email As String
        Public Property Name As Object
    End Class
```

but am getting this error when executing:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JimiTwo.PostmarkOne+Message' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'Messages', line 3, position 15.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Mike

Comment: Messages is a `List(Of Message)`. `_To` has the wrong name and is also a collection of objects etc. Note that this: `Public Property Messages() As Message` won't make `Messages` an array, this: `Public Property Messages As Message()` will (but use a List). In that answer, you can find a number of references (Web Sites) that can provide formatting, validation and generate .Net classes from your Json.

Comment: If the JSON property has a name non acceptable/prone to errors as a .Net property name (as `To`), you can use a `<JsonProperty("")>` attribute to change it. E.g., `<JsonProperty("To")> Public Property MsgTo As List(Of MessageTo)`